# Java class initialization

Tags: java, initialization

What does the following code actually do?

```
MyClass desc = new MyClass(){
            {
                setName("A");
                setAge(20);
            }
        };
```

Does it simply create MyClass instance and then calls the inner methods on it?

I have a feeling it does something more, such as, create an anonymous class with the methods called as an initialization block.

Can anyone provide an explanation?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code creates an instance of an anonymous sub-class of `MyClass`. It contains an instance initialization block that gets executed when the instance is created.

It's equivalent to :

```
public class SubClass extends MyClass
{
    {
        setName("A");
        setAge(20);
    }
}

MyClass desc = new SubClass ();
```

(except for the fact that here the sub-class is not anonymous).

And this code is equivalent to :

```
public class SubClass extends MyClass
{
    public SubClass ()
    {
        super ();
        setName("A");
        setAge(20);
    }
}

MyClass desc = new SubClass ();
```

since the instance initialization block get copied to the start of each constructor of the class.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it simply create MyClass instance and then calls the inner
>   methods on it?

**Instance Initializer block** is used to initialize the instance data member.

```
{
   setName("A");
   setAge(20);
}
```

There are certain rules regarding order of execution of initialization blocks and constructor. Let us list them down first and verify by writing a simple program.

```
Initialization blocks run in the order they appear in the program.
Instance initialization blocks run whenever a new instance of class is created.
```

[read more](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/initialization-blocks-constructors-and-their-order-of-execution/)